# Outlook AddIn detecting this.Application.NewMail but not seeing it as unread

Tags: email, outlook-addin

Morning,

I have written an Outlook add [outlook-addin](/questions/tagged/outlook-addin) in that detects a new mail then it should do some processing on all unread mail items, which should include the mail item that just arrived in the inbox as well as any others.

[image]

The issue is that my code fires on this event: **this.Application.NewMail**

Then it restricts the list of inbox items to be only the unread ones.

*(obviously it makes sense the email that just arrived should be classed as unread)*

However, the email that just arrived is not part of the unread collection.

The email that just arrived only gets picked up the next time an email arrives and this whole cycle is repeated, meaning the second email is not picked up until a 3rd email arrives.

I can't afford to have an email sitting then in an unprocessed state.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use the NewMail event - use NewMailEx instead. It passes the entry ids of the new emails separated by "," ([according o the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171304(v=office.11).aspx)). In practice, Outlook never passes multiple entryids, but rather fires NewMailEx for each new message.

Use the entry id to call `Namespace.GetItemFromID`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. However it seems that no matter what I use it will not be 100% robust. I am going to move to running my own TCP Listener in Azure that will process 1000's of emails and be totally scalable.